# Sharedpreferences gives me a null pointer

Tags: android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

Hey i have a little problem with my sharedpreferences, it gives me a nullpointerexception at the line 
    Editor edit = prefs.edit();

Do you see why i get the error?

I have searched the web for this error, and many have had something similar, but i haven't found someone who have had the same error on the same line as me, and the solutions weren't something that i could use.

Thanks for your help.

and here is the code from my Main class:

```
public class Main extends Activity{

Button bStart, bStop;
TextView tvView;
Spinner spinner1;
boolean stopValue;
int startkilometer;
String date;
SharedPreferences prefs;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    bStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);
    tvView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvView);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    date = getIntent().getStringExtra("datoen");
    startkilometer = getIntent().getIntExtra("startkm", 0);


SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    prefs.getBoolean("stopper", true);
    prefs.getInt("startkm", startkilometer);
    prefs.getString("datoen", date);



    stopValue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("stopper", stopValue);


    if(stopValue){
        bStart.setText("Start");
        bStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent start = new Intent("com.uniqueapps.runner.START");
                startActivity(start);
            }
        });
    }

    if(stopValue == false){
        bStart.setText("Stop");
        bStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent stop = new Intent("com.uniqueapps.runner.STOP");
                stop.putExtra("startkm", startkilometer);
                stop.putExtra("datoen", date);
                startActivity(stop);
            }
        });
    }

    KilometerSQL info = new KilometerSQL(this);
    info.open();
    String data = info.getData();
    info.close();
    tvView.setText(data);

    }




@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

super.onResume();       


}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.putBoolean("stopper", stopValue);
    edit.putInt("startkm", startkilometer);
    edit.putString("datoen", date);
    edit.commit();

    super.onPause();
}
```

My start class:

```
public class Start extends Main implements OnClickListener {

Button bStartTur;
EditText etDate, etKm;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start);
    bStartTur = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStartTur);
    bStartTur.setOnClickListener(this);
    etDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etdate);
    etKm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etKm);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    etDate.setText(format.format(new Date()));



}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String date = etDate.getText().toString();
    int startkilometer;
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.bStartTur:

        startkilometer = Integer.valueOf(etKm.getText().toString());


        Intent menu = new Intent("com.uniqueapps.runner.MENU");
        menu.putExtra("stopper", false);
        menu.putExtra("startkm", startkilometer);
        menu.putExtra("datoen", date);
        startActivity(menu);

        break;
    }

}

}
```

My stop class:

```
public class Stop extends Main implements OnClickListener {

Button bStop;
EditText sqllocations, kilometer;
int startkilometer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.stop);
    bStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bstopTur);
    bStop.setOnClickListener(this);
    sqllocations = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.locations);
    kilometer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Kilometer);

    sqllocations.setText("Unknown"); 


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    int startkilometer;
    int slutkilometer;
    startkilometer = getIntent().getIntExtra("startkm", 0);
    date = getIntent().getStringExtra("datoen");

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.bstopTur:


         slutkilometer = Integer.valueOf(kilometer.getText().toString());



        int kortekm = (slutkilometer - startkilometer);

        try{
        String locations = sqllocations.getText().toString();

        KilometerSQL entry = new KilometerSQL(this);
        entry.open();
        entry.createEntry(date, kortekm, locations);
        entry.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         Intent menu = new Intent("com.uniqueapps.runner.MENU");
            menu.putExtra("stopper", true);
            startActivity(menu);
            break;
    }
}

}
```

And my SQL:

public class KilometerSQL {

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "date";
public static final String KEY_KILOMETER = "kilometer";
public static final String KEY_LOCATIONS = "locations";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Kilometerdb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "kilometertable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_KILOMETER + " INTEGER, " +
                KEY_LOCATIONS + " TEXT NOT NULL);"


                );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    }

public KilometerSQL (Context c){
    ourContext = c;
}

public KilometerSQL open(){
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String date, int kortekm, String locations) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_ROWID, date);
    cv.put(KEY_KILOMETER, kortekm);
    cv.put(KEY_LOCATIONS, locations);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}

public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String [] columns = new String []{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_KILOMETER, KEY_LOCATIONS};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iDate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iKilometer = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_KILOMETER);
    int iLocations = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LOCATIONS);

    for (c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + c.getString(iDate) + " " + c.getString(iKilometer) + " " + c.getString(iLocations) + "\n";
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());    Just use this at onCreate();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your onCreate you're referencing a *local* variable of prefs, not the one as class field. So in the onResume `prefs` is still null.

Replace

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

with

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: That worked, thanks.. ;) But i still got one problem i see. My default boolean value is still false even though i set to true.
Do you see why?

Comment: Probably you've set it to `true`, so the saved value ovverride the default one. Do a "clean" test deleting the shared preferences (Manage Applications > MyApp > clear data)

Comment: That wasn't it, it didn't help to clean the app, or unistall it.

Comment: Here is a tutorial about how to use SharedPreferences in Android : http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/using-sharedpreferences-example

Comment: Btw you're getting the value from the prefs `prefs.getBoolean("stopper", true);` but you're not assigning it. Do you want the one from the Intent or the Preferences?

Comment: That tutorial looks a bit messy, didn't get anything from it.
I'm not experienced enough to convert data from one thing to another, it's easier to understand when i see how it fits in my own code.

Comment: I'm not quite sure i understand your question.
But my result with the boolean value, is that the first time i enter the app, i want the value to be true, and then i want the value from my activities, by that i mean i want the value to be saved and then loaded everytime i open the app. :)

Comment: You are getting twice your value, one from the preferences and one from your Intent. You use the Intent when you want to "pass" values from one Activity to another one. You use the Preferences when you want to store the value. You should probably just drop the `stopValue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("stopper", stopValue);` and keep `stopValue = prefs.getBoolean("stopper", true);`. But I'm not sure because I don't know how your app should work!

Comment: forgot to mention, my boolean value changes when i use 2 different buttons in my 2 other classes.
Therefore i have the getIntent().getBooleanExtra. ;)

Answer (score 1):

in your onCreate you're redeclaring `SharedPreferences prefs`, since it has already been declared in the Activity class you should just assign it with

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

The way you are doing it now, `prefs` will be a local variable inside `onCreate`, the activity `prefs` will still be null